# How come Log4J double the size of log file?

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

My spring application running `Log4j` through `common-logging` and `slf4j-log4j12`
In the following setting

```
log4j.appender.ROL=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ROL.Encoding=Unicode
log4j.appender.ROL.File=E:\\I_Told_Ya.log
log4j.appender.ROL.MaxFileSize=100000
log4j.appender.ROL.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.ROL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ROL.layout.ConversionPattern=%d -- %p -- %c -- %m%n
```

When I set

```
MaxFileSize=10000000
```

each log file grows until `19,488kb`

When I set

```
MaxFileSize=10000000
```

each log file grows until `196kb`

When I set

```
MaxFileSize=10Mb
```

each log file grows until `20,000kb`

Log4J always double the log size from my setting

So what is going on?

these are my dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: By curiosity, what does setting `Encoding` to `Unicode` mean? Unicode is not an encoding to start with...

Comment: @fge. You get sharp vision, that is the problem ! thanks!

Comment: Uh, you mean you don't have the problem anymore if you replace that with (I guess) UTF-8?

Comment: @fge yes. I mean, it works fine immediately with rolling per 10 Mb, but still stop rolling sometimes after a while. Open another thread [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234765/does-scheduler-start-a-new-thread?noredirect=1#comment33764409_22234765](here). But think it is a thread related issue. Just want to say you definitely nail the primary cause :)